# How many bytes should i allocate for base64 decode?

Tags: c, base64

I would like to use this https://opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.c.auto.html implementation of a base64 decoder but I don't know how much space should I allocate for it.

```c
unsigned char *buff = calloc(strlen(input_data) * SOMETHING, sizeof(unsigned char));
int len = Base64decode(buff, input_data);
```

Comment: According to [What is the space overhead of Base64 encoding?](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/01/30/what-is-the-space-overhead-of-base64-encoding/) we use 33% more storage than we could (6 bits instead of 8), so `len + len / 3` seems the optimal size.

Comment: Base64 uses 6 bit per byte and you decode to 8 bit per byte. That means you need 3 decoded bytes per 4 bytes encoded input.

Comment: @DavidRanieri `len + len / 3` would be the other way around. I would suggest `len * 3 / 4`

Comment: @Gerhardh oooops, you're right!

Comment: It is also possible to decode a Base64 string in place, without allocating memory at all.